# Can you access a single std::unique_lock from multiple threads?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, locking

I am having some trouble conceptualizing how `unique_lock` is supposed to operate across threads. I tried to make a quick example to recreate something that I would normally use a `condition_variable` for.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
unique_lock<mutex>* mLock;
void funcA()
{
    //thread 2
    mLock->lock();//blocks until unlock?Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //thread 1
    mLock = new unique_lock<mutex>(m);
    mLock->release();//Allows .lock() to be taken by a different thread?
    auto a = std::thread(funcA);
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000);//make sure thread is running
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    mLock->unlock();//Unlocks thread 2's lock?
    a.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you would normally need condition variable, than you need condition variable. `unique_lock` is just abstraction for mutex ownership. All synchronization it does is locking and unlocking mutex.

Comment: @zch This is purely to understand what is going on :-)

Comment: `unique_lock` is not meant to be shared, only to hold a lock across a *specific scope* (it's just a RAII wrapper for the mutex lock, nothing more). Of course you can try to misuse it, and to be blunt as far as misuse goes I think you really nailed it. ;)

Comment: A mutex is per resource (global); a lock is per thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't look at all right. First, [`release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/release) is "disassociates the mutex without unlocking it", which is highly unlikely that it is what you want to do in that place. It basically means that you no longer have a `mutex` in your `unique_lock<mutex>` - which will make it pretty useless - and probably the reason you get "access violation".

Edit: After some "massaging" of your code, and convincing g++ 4.6.3 to do what I wanted (hence the `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP`), here's a working example:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
void funcA()
{
    cout << "FuncA Before lock" << endl;
    unique_lock<mutex> mLock(m);
    //thread 2
    cout << "FuncA After lock" << endl;
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(500);//make sure thread is running
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);        //this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    cout << "FuncA After sleep" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Main before lock" << endl;
    unique_lock<mutex> mLock(m);
    auto a = std::thread(funcA);
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000);//make sure thread is running
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);        //this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    mLock.unlock();//Unlocks thread 2's lock?
    cout << "Main After unlock" << endl;
    a.join();
    cout << "Main after a.join" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure why you need to use `new` to create the lock tho'. Surely `unique_lock<mutex> mlock(m);` should do the trick (and corresponding changes of `mLock->` into `mLock.` of course).

Answer (score 12):

`unique_lock` should not be accessed from multiple threads at once.  It was not designed to be thread-safe in that manner.  Instead, multiple `unique_lock`s (local variables) reference the same global `mutex`.  Only the `mutex` itself is designed to be accessed by multiple threads at once.  And even then, my statement excludes `~mutex()`.

For example, one knows that `mutex::lock()` can be accessed by multiple threads because its specification includes the following:

> *Synchronization:* Prior `unlock()` operations on the same object shall *synchronize with* (4.7) this operation.

where *synchronize with* is a term of art defined in 4.7 [intro.multithread] (and its subclauses).

Comment: Wow, this was killing me. (Had been trying to use a manually .unlock()ed  unique_lock across threads because the condition_variable demands it. Took a while to figure out that the foot gun protector is itself a large foot gun. Nobody but myself to blame though.)

Comment: Is there a reference to this anywhere?  According to cppreference, `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` will satisfy the requirements of `Lockable` and can be used with `std::lock` (just like a mutex, i.e. unique_lock is a superset of a mutex).   I can't find anything that defines if this is meant to only be from one thread at a time or not.

Comment: In the standard, 4.7.1 Data races [intro.races] goes into excruciating detail about thread safety issues.  In a nutshell it defines *synchronization operations*.  These are identified throughout the std::lib with _Synchronization_ clauses on the specification of certain operations.  For example `mutex::lock()` has a synchronization clause.  Somewhere (maybe under [intro.races] it is also says that simultaneous operations that are `const` (and in the absence of _non_-`const`) are also thread-safe.  _Everything_ else is not designed to be called by more than one thread at a time.

Answer (score 3):

A lock is just an automatic guard that *operates* a mutex in a safe and sane fashion.

What you really want is this code:

```
std::mutex m;

void f()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    // ...
}
```

This effectively "synchronizes" calls to `f`, since every thread that enters it blocks until it manages to obtain the mutex.

A `unique_lock` is just a beefed-up version of the `lock_guard`: It can be constructed unlocked, moved around (thanks, @MikeVine) and it is itself a "lockable object", like the mutex itself, and so it can be used for example in the variadic `std::lock(...)` to lock multiple things at once in a deadlock-free way, and it can be managed by an `std::condition_variable` (thanks, @syam).

But unless you have a good reason to use a `unique_lock`, prefer to use a `lock_guard`. And once you *need* to upgrade to a `unique_lock`, you'll know why.

Comment: +1. In addition to what you just said, the *only* reason I have found so far to prefer `unique_lock` over `lock_guard` is because `condition_variable` requires a `unique_lock`. That concerns at the very least 10mloc (just so OP gets an idea). Admittedly only a very small part is C++11-ready but that doesn't change the underlying concepts and requirements.

Comment: @syam: Good point about `condition_variable`, thanks! (It's because the `wait` call needs to lock and unlock, which the simple `lock_guard` doesn't provide.)

Comment: Another useful feature of unique_lock is its moveable, so you can say: `auto stackLock = Lock();` which is a whole less wordy than `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> stackLock(m_lock);` [edit where `Lock` is a member function which returns `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_lock)`]

Comment: @MikeVine: Yeah... I'd generally say that by the time you're transferring ownership of locks, you're probably in fairly deep anyway, but your example is a pretty good idea.

Comment: @MikeVine Good point too, actually now that you say it I use this in a few places (not so many, though, I'm moving towards `LockedResource<...>` idioms that forbid you to access the protected resource unless you hold the lock -- but internally it indeed uses `unique_lock` for movability).

Comment: @KerrekSB Transferring ownership of locks is not necessarily a bad thing, again consider a function returning a `LockedResource<...>` object: it provides some API that you can only access when you actually hold the lock, and this is enforced by the compiler. Drastically reduces user errors.

Comment: @syam: Yeah, interesting... maybe you should post that, it sounds intriguing.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sure, but tomorrow... Right now I'm too tired to put a proper post together. ;) But really, once you understand the idea it's very straightforward: instead of first locking a mutex *then* accessing other functions (that theoretically could be accessed without locking the mutex first, but it would be incorrect) you have a single function that gives you a "smart pointer" providing both a lock and an API which you can operate through that object. [Here's the basic `LockedResource` template](http://pastebin.com/qNLdRMD2), I'm sure you'll figure out the rest. ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB [`LockedResource` now with usage example](http://pastebin.com/rWbRAJf0)

Comment: @syam: Nice, thanks! Basically a generic solution for providing a global lock around an arbitrary class? Would be nice if the mutex itself could be part of the wrapper, so that you can apply this to classes that were never designed for synchronisation.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes that's about it (minus the "global" lock, it's just a class instance lock). As to making the mutex part of it, I'm not sure: in the example the whole `MyClass` is locked, but in practice I often also have parts of the class which can be called without holding a lock first (the function synchronizes itself), ie. `LockedProxy` exposes only part of `MyClass` functionality. This was really intended as a means to enforce a lock around a specific API subset, but indeed it'd be straightforward to modify it and make it even more generic.

Answer (score 0):

As a side-note, the above answers skip over the difference between immediate and deferred locking of mutex:

```
#include<mutex>
::std::mutex(mu);
auto MyFunction()->void
{
   std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu); //Created instance and immediately locked the mutex
   //Do stuff....
}

auto MyOtherFunction()->void
{
   std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu,std::defer_lock); //Create but not locked the mutex
   lock.lock(); //Lock mutex
   //Do stuff....
   lock.unlock(); //Unlock mutex
}
```

MyFunction() shows the widely used immediate lock, whilst MyOtherFunction() shows the deferred lock.