# C++: Adding a sleep causes deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have this code.

```
std::thread t1(func1);
std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 2 ) );
std::thread t2(func2);
std::thread t3(func3);

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

In this code t1 takes a lock on mutex m1 and t2 is waiting to get the lock on m1. This code works as expected.
Now if I add a sleep for 5 seconds in t1, the program crashes with the following error -

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource deadlock avoided
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here are the backtraces of all the threads -

```
(gdb) thread 1
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007fa9eae827f1 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007fa9eb875957 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fa9eb87bae6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007fa9eb87ab49 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007fa9eb87b4b8 in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007fa9eb243573 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#7  0x00007fa9eb243ad1 in _Unwind_RaiseException () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#8  0x00007fa9eb87bd47 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007fa9eb877a23 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x000055d2f9bbe02f in std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock (this=0x55d2fbe062f8) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_mutex.h:264
```

```
(gdb) thread 2
#0  0x00007fa9ebd7ed2d in __GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex (threadid=140367767017216, thread_return=0x0, abstime=0x0, block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:89
#1  0x00007fa9eb8a6933 in std::thread::join() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x000055d2f9bb6e20 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at tests/benchmark-tests/benchmarkTest.cpp:294
(gdb)
```

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fa9ebd87d50 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0x7fa9eae40d30, remaining=remaining@entry=0x7fa9eae40d30) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
#1  0x000055d2f9bbeaf5 in std::this_thread::sleep_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > (__rtime=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/thread:373
```

My questions are -

1. Why is this crashing? It is saying deadlock avoidance but I am not able to understand what the deadlock is?
2. Does C++ have inbuild deadlock detection? Can that be disabled by some flag?

Added the code which reproduces the issue -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unordered_map>

class Worker {
    public:
        Worker() : workerLock(workerMutex, std::defer_lock) {}
        ~Worker() {
            workerLock.lock();
            workerLock.unlock();
        }
        void acquireWorkerLock() {
            workerLock.lock();
        }
        void releaseWorkerLock() {
            workerLock.unlock();
        }
        void work() {
            std::cout << "I'm working" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
        }
    private:
        std::mutex workerMutex;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> workerLock;
};

class WorkerManager {
    public:
        void newWorker(std::string name) {
            const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(managerMutex);

            bool workerAlreadyPresent = ( workers.find( name ) != workers.end() );
            if( !workerAlreadyPresent ) {
                Worker *worker = new Worker();
                workers.insert( {name, worker} );
            }
        }
        void work(std::string name) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(managerMutex);
            auto workerIt = workers.find( name );
            if( workerIt != workers.end() ) {
                Worker *worker = workerIt->second;
                worker->acquireWorkerLock();
                lock.unlock();
                worker->work();
                worker->releaseWorkerLock();
            }
        }
        void removeWorker(std::string name) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(managerMutex);
            auto workerIt = workers.find( name );
            if( workerIt != workers.end() ) {
                Worker *worker = workerIt->second;
                workers.erase(workerIt);
                lock.unlock();
                delete worker;
            }
        }
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, Worker*> workers;
        std::mutex managerMutex;
};

WorkerManager wm;

void func1() {
    wm.work("Foo");
    std::cout << "Work done by worker Foo\n";
}

void func2() {
    wm.removeWorker("Foo");
    std::cout << "Worker removed Foo\n";
}

void func3() {
    wm.newWorker("Bar");
    std::cout << "Worker added Bar\n";
}

int main() {
    wm.newWorker("Foo");
    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 2 ) );
    std::thread t2(func2);
    std::thread t3(func3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Backtrace for the above code -

```
(gdb) thread 1
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f79d03387f1 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f79d0bac957 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f79d0bb2ae6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f79d0bb1b49 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f79d0bb24b8 in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f79d0918573 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#7  0x00007f79d0918ad1 in _Unwind_RaiseException () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#8  0x00007f79d0bb2d47 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007f79d0baea23 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00005653edd0f690 in std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock (this=0x5653eeb65e98) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_mutex.h:264
#11 0x00005653edd0f048 in Worker::~Worker (this=0x5653eeb65e70, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at test.cpp:10
#12 0x00005653edd0f443 in WorkerManager::removeWorker (this=0x5653edf16140 <wm>, name="Foo") at test.cpp:57
```

```
(gdb) thread 2
#0  0x00007f79d06f1d2d in __GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex (threadid=140161156749056, thread_return=0x0, abstime=0x0, block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:89
#1  0x00007f79d0bdd933 in std::thread::join() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00005653edd0eb0e in main () at test.cpp:89
(gdb)
```

```
(gdb) thread 3
#0  0x00007f79d06fad50 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=0x7f79cff58cb0, remaining=0x7f79cff58cb0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
#1  0x00005653edd0fb2d in std::this_thread::sleep_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > (__rtime=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/thread:373
#2  0x00005653edd0f135 in Worker::work (this=0x5653eeb65e70) at test.cpp:21
#3  0x00005653edd0f339 in WorkerManager::work (this=0x5653edf16140 <wm>, name="Foo") at test.cpp:46
```

Comment: Instead of trying to describe the code, please *show* it to us. Please try to create a [mre] to show.

Comment: Sleeping while holding a mutex seems very odd. Very!

Comment: I have modified the question and added the smallest possible code in which I'm seeing the issue. Please take a look now.

Comment: Not sure about deadlock in your specific case, but `removeWorker` can be called at the same time the tail of `work` is doing the work. So a worker can be `delete`d while its method `work()` is still running.

Comment: @yeputons Yes. That is why I need the workerMutex. Since workerMutex will only be released after the work is done, worker destructor can not proceed while work is running.

Comment: @VinayakaB Ah, you have it in `~Worker()`. In that case I'd appreciate if you can update your question with exact backtraces from your code. Currently it mentions line 294. Also, try compiling with `-fsanitize=thread`, it may produce better error messages.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove the worker from the map at the end of `WorkerManager::work` function once the work is done?

Comment: @DanielLangr work can be called more than once for a single worker.

Comment: @yeputons Adding the `-fsanitize=thread` is suppressing the core dump. I have added the backtrace of the above program without this flag.

Comment: Maybe offtopic, maybe related: Shouldn't a destructor be noexcept? The destrcutor of `Worker` could currently throw an exception if the mutex throws an exception

Comment: @MikevanDyke This is just a sample code. Thanks for the reminder though. I will ensure that doesn't happen in the actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot lock a mutex through the same `std::unique_lock` twice. In your case, if the work is being done, the worker's mutex has been lock through its `workerLock`. Then, if another thread tries to remove the worker, it calls `lock` on the same unique lock in the worker's destructor. Quoting from the [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/lock):

> **Exceptions**
>
> If the mutex is already locked by this `unique_lock` (in other words, owns_lock is true), std::system_error...

IMO, a unique lock or any lock guard is not meant to be used outside of a single code scope (block).

---

Here is a proposed `Worker` that doesn't use a unique lock as a member variable:

```
class Worker {
  public:
    ~Worker() {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> workerLock(workerMutex);
    }
    void acquireWorkerLock() {
      workerMutex.lock();
    }
    void releaseWorkerLock() {
      workerMutex.unlock();
    }
    void work() {
      std::cerr << "I'm working" << std::endl;            
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
    }
  private:
    std::mutex workerMutex;
}
```

---

This question might be relevant: [unique_lock across threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18937564/580083). A short quote from the main answer provided by Howard Hinnant:

> `unique_lock` should not be accessed from multiple threads at once. It was not designed to be thread-safe in that manner. Instead, multiple `unique_lock`s (local variables) reference the same global `mutex`. Only the `mutex` itself is designed to be accessed by multiple threads at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lesson for me to read full documentation instead of skimming over it.